# Android ICS building process is too long and is not completed

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to build android ICS on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS virtual
machine in windows 7.

The build has been going on for 6 hours and now is stuck at a
message : Copy generated resources: SignatureTest

Can anyone suggest what may have gone wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enough memory and space in your virtual machine:

> It is also possible to build Android in a virtual machine. If you are running Linux in a virtual machine, you will need at least 16GB of RAM/swap and 30GB or more of disk space in order to build the Android tree.